# How to answer a closed question?

Tags: discussion, answers, closed-questions

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61054657/input-twice-to-pass-the-condition?noredirect=1#comment108031699_61054657) was closed yesterday for obvious reasons. One important function in question which answers were really depending on that wasn't in question. Then after the question was closed, OP left a comment that they had added the function which makes the question very clear.

How can I answer this question? Should I create a chat room?

Comment: The edit should push the question into the reopen review queue. Wait with your answer until it has been reopened.

Comment: You can't, unless it's reopened. Users with 3k reputation or more can vote to reopen if they believe the question is appropriate for the site.

Comment: It's reopened now.

Answer (score 8):

#### Edit the Question to include the comment, and then vote to reopen it.

Closed questions cannot and should not be answered at all. They have to be reopened to get an answer, and they can only be reopened if the Question content itself is an appropriate question. Comments don’t count. So edit the Question, and get it to a point where it should be opened, and then vote to reopen.

If you lack the privilege to vote to reopen, editing the Question will put it in the review queue, so people who do have that privilege will see it. Likewise, if you *do* vote to reopen, the Question goes in the review queue so the other four votes can be found.

If you lack the privilege to edit the Question, then you’ll only be able to suggest that edit. But that edit will go in its own review queue, to get that approved, and then once approved, the Question will go in the review queue for reopening.

Either way, it should be reopened quickly if, as you say, it is no longer a problem. Then you can answer it.

**Do not open a chat room or answer in comments or otherwise work around the closing.** Closed questions are closed for important reasons; they cannot receive answers because answering them (well) is impossible or inappropriate. As such, any workaround to communicate an answer to the asker is going to cause problems: if the question *could* be answered, it would be open (or in the process of being reopened).

Opening a chat room can be appropriate in cases where a question is simply never going to be reopened as it is too much of a discussion for Stack Overflow. Chat rooms are an appropriate place to have discussions, while questions are not. If the work to clarify and improve the Question so that it *can* be reopened is more involved and requires some back and forth, a chat room can also be great for that. But don’t use a chat room just to work around a Question closing—instead, work to get the Question reopened.

Comments are only for clarifying and improving the Question or Answer they’re attached to. Using them for any other purpose is terrible; please never do.

Comment: I upvoted this for the first bit, but the advice about not opening a chatroom seems unnecessary; there's no issue with opening a chatroom to discuss a question or work through the question's problem with a user if you are so inclined. In fact it's probably encouraged because it keeps the question side of SO clean and helps the asker get their solution/answer. It just doesn't happen because most users don't want to focus on such 1-on-1 tutoring.

Comment: If a chatroom is opened, and clarifications to the question are made within the chat, those clarifications should be edited into the question so that everyone not in the chat can benefit from the clarification. It may also have the benefit of getting the question reopened. This is of course the same advice given for clarifications made in comments; edit the question.

Comment: @TylerH Oh, opening a chat room in general is fine, but it’s not fine to do so just to evade the question being closed, especially when we’re just talking about the waiting time for it to be reopened. As Heretic Monkey says, we *really do not* want people to just take things to chat instead of editing and reopening questions.

Comment: @KRyan Yes, for sure; I agree a chatroom should not be a workaround to improving a question where possible. I'm envisioning moreso the types of problems that are so broad they'd require a whole series of questions to fully satisfy a (typically new) question asker.

Comment: @TylerH In such cases, they should be encouraged to post multiple Questions—though a chat room might well be the best place to give them that encouragement and guidance, it shouldn’t *replace* actually going about posting those Questions, I think. There’s definitely some room there for personal judgment though, and I can imagine circumstances where I wouldn’t bother with multiple Questions and just leave it to chat. So yeah, I agree with that. Do you feel my Answer doesn’t well cover that? (Note I did recently edit it a little bit to cover some of that.)

Comment: @KRyan re: multiple question, it really depends. These are usually the users that struggle with posting quality / on-topic questions. Asking them to go beyond and make *multiple* on-topic questions of good quality is usually too big of an ask. I think the edit does help clarify things.

Comment: Personally I would love to see an option to create a chatroom for every question where users could drop comments out of sight of the main question (chat would load up in a sidebar/column or something). The chatrooms could be accessible from the question page or by searching in chat.SO for them. This way we'd allow for quick, asynchronous, fire and forget conversations with OP via chat that also serve to cleanup comments that may be too chatty or are temporal such as clarification questions/requests or even partial/whole answers. This would leave comments for things like security/caution notes.

Comment: @TylerH Yeah, I have *long* wished for a (non-moderator) way to take comments to a chat room, instead of only getting that option *after* a comment-discussion has gotten out of hand. Sometimes you just know it’s going to, but the options for dealing with it are really limited, especially if there are already some comments you’d want to capture in the chat room.

Comment: @KRyan Not sure why you want SO to built a troll heaven...

Comment: `if the question could be answered, it would be open`. To me this kindof ignores the shortcomings in the closure system. IMO there a lot of questions that are aggressively closed and will not be reopened, that if given some attention and restructuring could lead to helping people who currently just get shutdown. This is especially true with questions closed as duplicates, whose closures often seem to me to be shortsighted and miss the point of the question, in addition to being plain unhelpful to the OP.

Comment: ```
Do not open a chat room or answer in comments or otherwise work around the closing. Closed questions are closed for important reasons; they cannot receive answers because answering them (well) is impossible or inappropriate. As such, any workaround to communicate an answer to the asker is going to cause problems: if the question could be answered, it would be open (or in the process of being reopened).
```

it smells authoritarian approach to questions. Maybe those who closed the question don't know that it could be answered.