Why could it be that my java question about searching and replacing in string was badly received?
Two days ago, I posted Placeholders wrongly replaced with % char. I soon received one downvote and a close vote.
A little later the question received another 3 others downvotes and 1 upvote; for a current total of 4 downvotes, 1 upvote, and 1 close vote.
As the close review queue is busy, I don't think the review will be completed. So I will not have feedback from reviewers.
I tried to understand why my post have been downvoted:

It has a minimal reproducible example that is self-sufficient, and you just need a compiler and copy/paste to make it works.
It has good tags, not ugly formatted code or not-related content
There is example input with expected and actual output
There is a quick explanation of my objective. I even edited it to add details
I received answers that seem well-received and useful. I even accepted one that answer to my question.

I don't know what is the issue with my post, or how to improve it.

Note that receiving answers often has no correlation with question quality/on-topicness/etc. There are many who will answer anything that even remotely resembles a question (even if it's the 10th time it was asked just that day). I'm not implying that's your case.

[1/2] The only thing missing for me in the question is with which part you are actually having problems with. There are some problems, like starting % missing, but there's no indication what your problem with fixing is. Overall, the question reads a lot like "here is my code, debug it for me". When looking at the answers, you also notice that non of them actually fixes your code; they provide other algorithms for reaching the goal, but non references your code.

@DanMašek I understand, but a good question is also one that can be answered, a bad one can sometimes just not be answered or with bad explaination. So IMO it's a point that can help to know if the question can be improved or not

I wouldn't worry about a single close-vote just yet. The downvotes... Eh, maybe people think you're taking the wrong approach? Impossible to tell...

[2/2] If your goal was to get a better algorithm, then a "How do I find and replace ..." question should have been asked instead of a debugging question.

I'm not looking for a better algorithm. I know a single close vote is not enough to worry about it, but 4 downvote is enough. I checked for duplicate, and all possible post was about replacing known one, which is not my case. Also, I edited my question to add explaination about the issue

The initial rapid fire downvote was probably because the initial version contained an == string comparison. That's just too common and wildly documented a problem to have any right of existing in a Stack Overflow question. It is not why I would downvote, but it is definitely the type of problem that will cause people to shoot from the hip.

Hi folks, thanks for sharing your suggestions with Elikill58 regarding their question. Please note that the answer box is down below. When someone asks for feedback on Meta, it is not only appropriate but encouraged that you post your thoughts/feedback as an answer, not in the comments. Reserve comments for discussion about this Meta question.

Downvote because of == even if it doesn't change anything in this MRE is wild imo...

Hover the mouse button over the downvote button to see the tooltip. It will read "this question does not show any research effort". Quite some people stop reading right there.

"There is example input with expected and actual output..." Maybe the example input is not sufficient to represent all interesting cases. More and different examples might be helpful.

@CodyGray I tried to post a comment as an answer but it was deleted by yivi, Cerbrus, Ocaso Protal.  I'm going to stop participating in this platform period if my efforts to formulate honest answers are being wasted.  Do you know what the deletion reason was?

Finally, the close vote were real as my question got closed...

@java-addict301 It has been undeleted now.

@java-addict301 The users who voted to delete your answer were misusing their deletion privileges. Simple as that. It seems that it has been corrected now. If it happens again, you can raise a moderator flag on the post.

How did you wind up getting stuck with this homespun %foo% placeholder string format in the first place? Smells like an XY problem because there are already templating libraries that handle all the edge cases. Reinventing the wheel probably isn't a good approach to whatever your real problem X is. If you provide context for the real problem this templating system is intended to solve, your question might be better received.

@ggorlen I'm not making HTML content, and not using spring. Also, I didn't said it in the post but I don't want to use an external library to do this

@Elikill58 Templating isn't just for HTML content. Why don't you want to use an external library? Your use case is still unclear, and you can push back, but the fact of the matter is this is a common factor for poorly-received questions.

I already explained my use case... Also, some people are searching why I'm doing this, and then say I didn't explained it (even if it's not necessary)... I get an answer to my question, because someone read it completly and understood it. Also, asking for lib is off-topic. I proposed something vanilla, so I expect to have something vanilla, not "use Guava to do this few lines thing". Asking me to change % to something else would be off-topic. So, both link you gave could not answering. The only thing unclear is what you read about the question

Not a Java expert in any way, but this is my take:
The question seems to be about a very, very well trodden path. Namely: search and replace placeholders/variables in a template-like string. I'd be surprised if there weren't already many working solutions for a task like that in Java.
An extremely quick search got me this. I'm sure with some minutes devoted to the task, and more knowledge, I'd find even more (and maybe better) things.
Then, the problem statement is a bit messy. You are trying to accomplish the above; but instead of asking directly about the above (which again, you probably shouldn't since it's likely an already solved problem), you offer your own approach at solving it.
The approach is clearly wrong, and not worth fixing, so the answers instead proffer alternative solutions.
I think this would be enough to justify a poor reception for your question. I don't feel it is actually fixable, and to make matters worse users already answered.
In the end, you need to understand that I'm mostly guessing why other users voted how they did. To me, the upvote seems harder to explain than the downvotes, but as we are not the voters, we can only offer opinions (more or less informed) on the question itself.

So it would mostly be because of the subject rather than the question itself?

I don't fully understand what are you trying to take away from my answer. It's about the whole thing: I feel it's a poorly stated, and wrong approach; and the problem wasn't properly researched. Please, do not take this the wrong way: it's perfectly fine to make this kind of mistake. If anything, I take issue with the answerers. I believe they should probably have suggested you for alternative solutions (e.g. by linking to other questions), or simply have told you what to search for. And once more: this is just my opinion, other users are very likely going to disagree.

(or voted to close as a dupe)

"you offer your own approach at solving it" - isn't that considered to be a good thing? I would typically expect a "how do I implement X?" question with no attempt at solving it to be met (quite reasonably) with responses of the "So which bit exactly are you having problems with?" / "Stack Overflow is not a code writing service" variety.

@gasman The difference is that the question is not "how do I do X" with an attempt provided, it's an XY problem where they're focused on their own solution instead of the actual problem (which is probably a dupe anyway)

Yeah, that's the thing. On a "how to" question, code is not even required (although it's many times welcome to give context, expectations, etc). But here the code provided simply does the question no favors. The question is, nominally, about X; but in reality is about Y (the code). If it were about X, it would be a dupe at best, if it were about Y, it would be a trivial "fix my code for me", almost a typo situation. @gasman

Not to be rude, but in simpler terms it means that your question could've been a google search or whatever search engine that feels convenient.
The fact that there exist 100s of materials that describes how the problem can be solved.
To conclude, yes, your post is clear and precise and to the point with a working example. I think the issue gets down to what people find worth solving or spend time on.
People with teaching mentality will always try to answer or explain everything in detail. But they are very rare.
I hope you got the answer that you were looking for.

"...it gets down to what people find worth solving or spend time on..." To be fair, I feel like this should not be a downvote reason. If a question is uninteresting to some, it can simply remain unanswered. I can ignore it and move on to other more interesting questions.

I agree with NDDNC, find something that isn't for you should not be a reason to be agree to it. Also, yes I found an answer on my post, that I didn't found after all of my searched before posting it. But I will not prove I made searched

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Unfortunately, we can't really force people to be consistent in downvote reasons. We don't even require them to explain their downvotes.

@Elikill58 "But I will not prove I made searched" Fine by me. But then I will assume you didn't. You decide what you do and others decide what they do.


I don't know what is the issue with my post, or how to improve it.

Your question is a duplicate of literally thousands - perhaps tens of thousands at this point - of questions asking to do effectively the same thing, the answer to which is always "use a regular expression". When I go to ask a question using the exact same title as yours...

one of the suggested similar questions (shown in above image) is an answered one from 2019 with the accepted answer using a regular expression. Yes it's C# not Java, but the principle remains the same.
So, you didn't bother using the site feature that is literally designed to stop people posting duplicate questions. That's an immediate downvote from me, and it should be a close-as-duplicate vote too, except I can't be bothered finding an appropriate duplicate because I have better things to do with my time.

Except that the question in question is not a "how-to" question, but a "what's-wrong-with-my-code" question, so it is not a duplicate of that boatload of "how-to" questions that you reference.

Any "what is wrong with my code" question involving text search and replace, that does not use regular expressions, is a how-to question.

are "what's wrong with my code" questions on topic? what is expected of those questions to be considered on topic?

Yes, they're on-topic, @Christoph, as long as a minimal, reproducible example is included. It is reasonable for an answer to say, "don't do it that way, do it like this instead" and point to an existing Q&A, but that is an answer, not a duplicate.

I know it's an enormous tangent... there's (at least) 3-4 types of "what's wrong with my code" questions: someone... (1) tries to use some API/library and it goes wrong (2) tries to implement a serious algorithm (3) tries to implement some toy algorithm as an exercise, say fibonacci (4) writes some arbitrary business logic for their game or whatever. 3 and 4 are struggling with basic understanding of programming. for this site, I see value in (1) and (2), but none in (3) and (4). it has value to one person. nobody else will google anything and get that Q&A or find it valuable.

I want to make a complete answer about all reactions I received. Actually, the question is closed for the second time. (So I had good reason of worrying...).
I made multiple edits to:

Add new examples
Add explaination of the issue
Add explaination of how I'm using this code
Add example of previous tested code

Actual general opinion is globally bad. I got multiple comment that were asking for details, explaination or other. And, something that is similar between those comment is that... It doesn't need answer. Mostly because it's already on the post, or because it's asking off-topic things.
Let me explain.
When I post my question, I tried to make it quick as possible, focused on the issue and the code. It's not necessary to explain my life or give the full code where it's used. With that, I made a minimal example, actual behavior, expected behavior and code example. A sufficient question for me. I made it quick because I know some people are not reading the full post. And, by adding the stuff as I said before, people are reading less part of the post...
Because of adding content, people are asking me to get placeholders list even if it's written "placeholders are not known", are telling me it can be do with string.replace(), or asking for search but if I'm asking, it's because I didn't find it... And proove you made search is hard, mostly when other post are simply asking about how to replace string, not by searching string.
Another things reported is because it seems to be a simple question (as SO has a lot...), so people doesn't like it. But it's not. It's not because it's refering to simple concept (replace) because the question is simple.
They also think it's a duplicate, but there is no similar question. The only thing near is another answer. So, my question itself is not a duplicate.
What happend after the meta post
I received the meta effect as expected. In fact, I got 15 upvotes (for 18 downvotes) for a total of -3. It's a lot of votes. There is clearly a disagreement between people. I tried to answer to most of the comment, but I get rid of this. I'm not letting my question like that, closed with a nice, clear and good answer. With another answer that proposed another way (which is not perfect). The question itself can help people, I just hope it will not be deleted.
To conclude
Most of my meta SO post learn me something, I got real answers, even if it were hard to accept. Here, I feel as I just got bad feedback that I don't really understand, and if I do all we are asking to me, it would be the worst question I would ever made as it would be unreadable (IMO, it's a little true yet...). And I think it's sad. I FF to fix a question, because there is no obvious issue that can be fix easily.
After that, I posted another question that also got downvote and close vote (without beeing closed). I don't understand why, but I'm just affraid of asking why (not closed yet so no real reason to do it apparently... but it will simply be deleted by roomba before... and I'll stay without answer...).
Sorry for all complain. Just have to say things. We're humans.

Don't feel bad about the downvotes.  You might have done something wrong, but it's not what you think.
The first thing you might actually have done wrong was to think that you've done something wrong.  But in fact: downvotes aren't for you.  Downvotes don't mean, "You did something wrong; don't do that again".  Downvotes mean, "This Q/A pair is not a good long-term fit for Stack Overflow's repository".
The second thing you might have done wrong was to think that Stack Overflow is here to help you.  Stack Overflow is not here to help you.  Stack Overflow is here to build the aforementioned repository, of high-quality questions and answers that future readers will likely benefit from.  Whether you get the help you wanted is (in Stack Overflow's view) purely secondary.
So the question you want to ask is, Did you get the help you wanted?. If you did, great: That's what you wanted!  Don't worry so much about the downvotes.
But, in closing, you do have my sympathy.  I perfectly agree that even if they're not supposed to, downvotes hurt, and can really feel like you're being punished in some way.  I perfectly agree that Stack Overflow feels like a place you can get help, and that its focus on the sanctity of the long-term repository can end up feeling pretty rude to you, the original questioner on which the site, in part, depends.
But these arguments — that downvotes aren't supposed to feel punitive, and that helping you is not the site's primary focus — are still sort of a "party line" around here, and I think they explain the reaction to your question.

I'm not mad, I just want to understand. Also, your answer doesn't really answer to post question, it's full of opinion but nice xD

Paraphrasing - “downvotes are not supposed to feel punitive” - then why do they remove reputation? No one has ever been able to answer this for me because the original statement is patently false.  They were clearly designed to feel punitive and to shame and make transgressors a public example.  Otherwise, they would not be both public and inherently punitive.

@java-addict301 the original design was to invoke voluntary participation through gamification, and points are part of that game. But one can't help but notice that videogames have long ago evolved away from singular point systems. It's not really of this time anymore.

I believe the community here tends to be a bit too strict or critical with questions.
In my view, your question is valid and reflects a situation that a junior developer could face, and I think that when a question includes an incorrect or suboptimal approach, it’s more helpful to guide the asker toward a better solution through answers, rather than closing the question outright.
While I understand that some questions may seem 'basic' to experienced developers or computer scientists, this strict approach can make less experienced users hesitant to ask questions.
About the inadequate research effort: sometimes, when a person is inexperienced in a certain subject, they don't even know what to search for.
I think this platform should be for anyone, not only for the experts trying to solve sophisticated problems.

"when a person is inexperienced in a certain subject, they don't even know what to search for"... that's not an argument against closing. We can guide them to relevant resources in the comments, or close as a dupe, etc. SO is not a code writing service nor a help desk. We are here to build "a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming", not just solving everyone's issues, whether they are an expert or a novice. There are forums, sub-reddits, discord channels, etc. for that.

Guiding a novice asker to understand what they are actually searching for is an alternative way of answering the question, rather than aggressively hitting the downvote button. I don't think their question falls into 'avoid to ask' type of questions described here: stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask either. It includes the desired behavior and the code to reproduce it. It's actually a specific case of a more general problem as @yivi mentioned, and a guiding answer could be telling that, while I think its okay to ask specific programming problems too based on stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

I have upvoted yivi's answer. Let's talk about your answer: it portrays the community as something it isn't and also gives generic advice (something like be nice, help everyone) which SO never aspires to be. To clarify, I am not so much on the side that believes every question should be stellar (and not localized), but again, you're interpreting  having standards as harshness, which I think comes from not fully comprehending the goal and scope of SO.

Their question: why did they not like my question. My answer: because the community tends to be harsh against the newbies, and the questions they don't find complex enough. In my previous comment I also assessed the actual standards (based on sources from SO itself)/ and how they are practiced in reality. So, assuming that this question is valid based on the fact that it is not closed yet, I just provided a valid answer.

"community tends to be harsh against the newbies", that is factually weong. See these: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24870 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152066 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342779 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413547 and many more threads (including dupe targets). Your assumptions in your comment regarding this specific question are not reflected in your answer. Maybe you'd want to [edit] your answer from a generic "SO is toxic" to something else.

"...they don't even know what to search for..." You may not find the right keywords to search efficiently, but at the very least people could input their own question into google and check the first links that come up and then describe the results. While research may not be very helpful, it can always be done by everyone at all levels, I'd say. One just has to do it.

rather than aggressively hitting the downvote button There is no such thing as aggressively downvoting. The up/downvote is a pure indication of "do I find this question/answer" useful or not. It reflects a personal opinion on the merit of the question or answer. No emotions involved at all.

@GeertBellekens You mean you never happily upvoted anything at all? I sagree that a downvote is not an aggression. It's the normal functioning of the site.

"I believe the community here tends to be a bit too strict or critical with questions." - No individuals are, there is no community. Nada. Not even meta is a community, we suck at working together.

@smgtkn - “My answer: because the community tends to be harsh against the newbies, and the questions they don't find complex enough.” - This author has 1000x more reputation then you have so they are definitely not a new user. Being a new user doesn’t change the community expectations for the quality of your contribution. Heck the majority of their 4000+ reputation comes from answering programming questions not asking them. I hate to be “that individual” but it’s hard to take your feedback seriously given the amount of contributions you have done so far yourself. It’s written as that jr dev

As a professional Java developer for 10 years, I can tell you there is nothing wrong with your question.  This community is unfortunately often very unfriendly and probably assumed you were asking a homework question.
Questions this well researched would be accepted with open arms on most other SE sites.  Don’t take it personally, just avoid asking questions at all costs if you don’t like downvotes.  I’m sorry folks, but it’s the ugly truth.

Advising people not to ask questions on a Q&A site is rather dubious advice.  While there are certainly issues on Stack Overflow with people being overly strict with what they consider a good vs. bad question, this advice regarding how to address that is unhelpful.

"Questions this well researched..." I would not have thought so for this question. There may be different standards out there for what a well researched question is. Maybe there should be a meta discussion about that.

@RyanM "...this advice regarding how to address that is unhelpful..." It's the opinion of the answerer. Could be that he genuinely thinks that not asking is currently the best option for information seekers. Maybe he/she is erring there, but unhelpful?

@RyanM I’m really not advising people to not post questions as much as I am telling them to expect downvoted when they do.  The downvotes really don’t have anything to do with whether a question is well researched, which is why I give this advice.  Take the countless questions that highly rated but had zero research effort.  Here’s a random one for example.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966552/what-is-the-difference-between-docker-and-docker-compose   The point is, you will almost inevitably be downvoted if you post a question.  What users do with this info is their prerogative.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Perhaps my phrasing could have been better.  I meant that it basically amounts to "there's nothing you can do" and offers little in the way of actionable advice for people who do have questions to ask, even to avoid the claimed reasoning of "probably assumed you were asking a homework question" (there are plenty of ways to avoid this perception).

@java-addict301 "The point is, you will almost inevitably be downvoted if you post a question."  That's objectively false, though. Of questions asked in the past year (including deleted ones), roughly 3/4 are not net-downvoted (274,852 scoring -1 or below, 548,684 scoring 0, and 163,825 scoring 1 or above).

@RyanM I saw this too. There is essentially not enough voting going on to determine if the majority of new questions is really good, really bad or just boring and not worth a vote or something else. If we wanted to find out we would have to random sample some new questions and rate them all.
